# What does the "LE" in Starcraft maps stand for

Tags: starcraft-2

A lot of the (especially tournament) maps of Starcraft 2 end with "LE". Does it have any meaning or does it stand for something?

Comment: Do yo have an example?

Comment: Tal'darim Altar LE

Answer (score 22, accepted):

LE stands for Ladder Edition.

There is also RE, which is Revised Edition, and SE, which is Second Edition.

LE maps are those that Blizzard tweaks and modifies so that they can be used in ladder matches.